# stay connection always on web server by android divice

Tags: java, android, webserver

I want to stay connection on web server using php by android app.by java coding
suppose when get any new input from webserver (by url php) android app make a Toast with the input and run the app on background service how I do it.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

simple way is use websocket ,
 
 1. webserver should enable websocket , create a websocket endpoint
 
 2. android app connect the websocket endpoint  
 
 3. webserver can push msg to app by endpoint
 
 4. then android receive msg 
 

 
you can reference these page:  
 
https://github.com/codebutler/android-websockets
 
http://socketo.me/